# Extracting and referencing multiple CSS files in ejected create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have an ejected create-react-app (webpack version 3.8.1) that will be implemented as a third-party widget on other websites.
The components are rendered in multiple iframes using r[eact-frame-component](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component).

When styling the components inside iframes I include the css in the head of the iframe.
Right now I'm doing it by loading the css into a string like this:

```
// IframeComponentOne.js
const innerStyles = require("./iframe-component-one-styles.scss").toString();

render() {
  return (
    <Frame
        head={<style>{innerStyles}</style>}
      >
      <CompA />
      <CompB />
      ...
    </Frame>
  )
}

// IframeComponentTwo.js
const innerStyles = require("./iframe-component-two-styles.scss").toString();

render () {
  return (
    <Frame
        head={<style>{innerStyles}</style>}
      >
      <CompC />
      <CompD />
      ...
    </Frame>
  )
}
```

However, to minimize bundle size, and defer css loading, I would like to extract the css into separate files and link to them in the iframes like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Frame
      head={<link rel="stylesheet" href="specific-frame.[hash].css">}
    >
    <CompX />
    <CompY />
    ...
  )
</Frame>
```

I'm aware that I probably need to use [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to extract the different innerStyles, but can't the webpack setup right.

How would a webpack setup for this look?
How do I reference the extraced css bundles with content hashes in the head of the iframe components?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to Webpack 4, you can do this without much additional configuration with [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).

With webpack 3, you will need this configuration in your webpack config file

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ]
}
```

We cannot say much without looking at your webpack config. but more or less, something along these lines should get you your desired functionality.